# TJSONObject Destroy method error

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe4

Trying to parse JSON file using the TJSONObject (Delphi XE4).

After parsing I would like to destroy TJSONObject to prevent memory leak, but:

```
procedure TfmMain.ReadIngrJSON(const fName: string);
var i: integer;
    S: TStringList;
    JSONObject, innerObject: TJSONObject;
    innerArray: TJSONArray;
begin
S:=TStringList.Create;
try
  S.LoadFromFile(fName);
  JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S.Text) as TJSONObject;
  if Assigned(JSONObject) then
    begin
      SetLength(ingrArray, JSONObject.Size);
      for i := 0 to JSONObject.Size-1 do
        begin
          ingrArray[i].id:=JSONObject.Get(i).JsonString.Value;
          innerObject:=JSONObject.Get(ingrArray[i].id).JsonValue as TJSONObject;

          innerArray:=innerObject.Get('en').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
          ingrArray[i].name[0]:=innerArray.Get(0).Value;
          ingrArray[i].units[0]:=innerArray.Get(1).Value;

          innerArray:=innerObject.Get('ru').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
          ingrArray[i].name[1]:=innerArray.Get(0).Value;
          ingrArray[i].units[1]:=innerArray.Get(1).Value;
          innerArray:=nil;
        end;
      innerObject.Destroy;

      for i := 0 to Length(ingrArray)-1 do
        listIngredients.Items.Add(ingrArray[i].name[1]);

    end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('no JSON data');
finally
  JSONObject.Destroy;  //here is an error 'invalid pointer operation'
  S.Free;
end;

end;
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: why not using `SuperObject` ? it uses refcounting so you can forget about creating and freeing. it is also tested by years of wide use and DBx JSOn is reported many times for bugs or inefficency. http://superobject.googlecode.com/git/readme.html

Comment: BTW `try` should go AFTER object creation, not before it. Don't know if you face that particular error right now, but your customers may be hit by it, when attempting to `Destroy` garbage pointer.

Comment: I should better keep my mouth shut but: Why aren't you using `.Free()`? An 'invalid pointer operation' is usually thrown when you forcefully try to destroy an object that has already been destroyed. `Free()` first checks if the object is assigned and then attempts to destroy it. But you probably have a reason to do so, I don't really know anything about JSON in Delphi...

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful `.Free` may help you if the object var was pre-zeroed (IOW it was another object's property) or after you used `FreeAndnil` (which many Delphi gurus consider harmful). In this particular code it might hide on problem (nil-pointer case), really. But it would not and cannot give any protection with the garbage-pointer case.  PS. `.Free` was introduced for object destructors, leveraging the mentioned properties auto-zeroing feature. What it would be used in general code instead of destructor was just unforeseen deviation from planned pathway :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: I have already used superobject. And now I want to use DBXJSON ))

Comment: @Romowski then you also have to learn about Delphi objects and managing their ownership and lifespan.

Comment: `JSONObject:=nil; JSONObject.Free;` helps
but there is also memory leaks ((((

Comment: `innerArray:=nil;` obviously leaks; dunno what you do later with `ingrArray` but if you later do similar `ingrArray := nil` it would leak too. However this particular question is about "invalid pointer operator", not about leak. If you want to ask about leaking - that is to be another question.

Comment: @Arioch'The `innerArray:=nil` most certainly does not leak

Comment: FWIW, even if you were responsible for destroying `innerObject` (and you are not), you would be leaking because you called the destructor outside the loop. But anyway, you are not responsible for destroying it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you're sure that `.Get` here ensures ownership by `innerObject` then i have to agree. I just don't know DBX JSON in those details and fast scan through docwiki did not showed this.

Comment: Now, you did not gorkked objects life time management. Your edited code still is leaking: it would leak `S` if any exception happens inside `JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S.Text) as TJSONObject;`. Also using TStringList just to read the file w/o changes looks like overkill to me. Perhaps TStringStream/TFileStream

Comment: @Romowski you still did not put correct TAG with your Delphi version but as a blind guess i suggest you looking at TFile.ReadAllText rather than misusing TStringList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct pattern - even built into Delphi Code Templates is

```
Object-var := Object-Class.Create; // or any other way to create the instance
try
    // ...
finally
  Object-var.Destroy;
end;
```

Instead you put object creation into the middle of code between `try` and `finally` which gives you warranty that:

- If some exception would happen in `S.LoadFromFile(fName);` this would call `Destroy` over garbage-pointer.
- If some exception would happen in `JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S.Text) as TJSONObject;` this would call `Destroy` over garbage-pointer.
- If `nil` is the result of `JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S.Text) as TJSONObject;` this would call `Destroy` over `nil` pointer;

---

Overall i heard little good about DBX JSON - many people complained about bugs or slow work. And you also looks having troubles understanding what is object lifetime and how to manage it in Delphi. For both this reasons i think you better use years-tested refcounting-bases JSON library instead of DBX.

http://superobject.googlecode.com/git/readme.html

Comment: Arioch - isn't it Object-var.Free instead of Destroy? :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy `Destroy` is perfectly fine since you know for sure that the reference has been assigned. If the `try` executes, then the object reference is assigned. `Free` is only really needed in destructors. But for consistency we tend to use it everywhere.

Comment: @whosrdaddy intended pattern was using `.Destroy`, but it was hi-jacked by unexpected trend to use `.Free` outside of object destructors later. However that is just interesting historical fact of next to none  practical value.

Comment: Ok, thanks to both of you. I will remember the keyword "consistency" in this story :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not your responsibility to free the reference returned by the call to `Get`. That responsibility lies with the object that you call `Get` on, in your code that is `JSONObject`. You must remove the line that calls `innerObject.Destroy`.

The reason you are encountering a *invalid pointer operation* error is that `JSONObject` is trying to destroy an object that you already destroyed.

---

You typically do not call `Destroy` in case the reference on which you call it happens to be `nil`. Instead call `Free` which performs the `nil` check and skips the call to `Destroy` if the reference is nil.

Finally, your use of finally is not correct. The correct pattern is:

```
obj := TSomeClass.Create;
try
  // use obj
finally
  obj.Free; // obj.Destroy is also fine in this case because obj <> nil
end;
```

You must put the `try` immediately after the constructor assigns to the reference. If you put it before, then your call to `Free` can act on an uninitialized reference. If you don't put it immediately after, then you may leak.

For your JSON object you'd write it like this:

```
JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S.Text) as TJSONObject;
if Assigned(JSONObject) then
  try
    ....
  finally
    JSONObject.Free;
  end;
```

Or equally you might do this:

```
JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S.Text) as TJSONObject;
try
  if Assigned(JSONObject) then
  begin
    ....
  end;
finally
  JSONObject.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Oh, i did not spot THAT `.Destroy`. Good catch! it is yet another garbage-pointer after `for i := 0 to -1 do`.

BTW, about ownership - i cannot find this claim of yours arounf http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue - is it published in manuals ? and what if i actually want to detach JSONValue from its root and keep it as a separate object ?

Comment: @Arioch'The It's just a simple double free error. Invalid pointer is the hallmark for that. Documentation for `TJSONObject` is, er, sparse. But all the examples you will find back up my claim. The [`Owned`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONAncestor.Owned) property defaults to `True` so far as I can tell.

Comment: Your comment did not help. Don't be shy. Tell me in what way it did not help. What did you do, and how did the behaviour change? If the best you can do is say "don't helped", that doesn't make it very easy for us to help.

Comment: Thanks for link. Reading "owned by the byte container" i can only wonder what they meant by b.c. here. And reading http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONFalse.ToBytes i can only wonder how they expect a simple dynamic array to be the owner for anything! ...and i thought SuperObject is badly documented ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, it's a total train wreck. Another piece of code that can only be used if you have the source code at hand. Anyway, a quick websearch shows a handful of examples that back up what I say. I'm 99% confident that I am right here. Probably "don't helped" actually means that the exception went away but the leak remains. But the leak is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @Romowski 1) http://maddog.sitengine.ru/smart-question-ru.html and for example talking about exception just *required* tellign in which particular line the exception happened 2) in the comments to the question you told that something "helped" to Invalid Pointer error. So i wonder wether "Invalid Pointer" fixed or not, by ANY of advices.

Comment: sorry for "don't helped" ) I have write everything as you wrote here, but exemption is still appears

Comment: @Romowski "exception", not "exemption". Are you realyl need practicing your English or perhaps better use rsdn.ru/sql.ru/Delphi Masters / Delphi Kingdom / etc ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: it was a misprint (

Comment: I don't think you needed to edit the question. What you should do is upvote the helpful answers and accept the answer which solved the problem.